# How to change enigma settings in Typescript

Tags: typescript

So I have an Enigma 1 machine "working" here: [repo](https://github.com/eli-ott/enigma-machine) without any settings set to it, it returns the same results as other emulators.

But when I try to change either the `ring setting` or the `rotor setting`, my result differs from the other emulators.

As a  main inspiration I've followed [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712506/enigma-replica-not-yielding-expected-result) and it lead me to having a machine that works without any settings.

But from what I understand from this answer, the rotor setting changes the rotor position without changing the expected output from the rotor wiring, which means that for the Enigma 1 Rotor 1 the expected output for.

My other problem too is that when I check the output of each rotor it gives the good resultnig according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712506/enigma-replica-not-yielding-expected-result). For example if I change the rotor setting to 1, for the first rotor I get `A->D` and when I try a second time after the rotation I get `A->I`.

So I believe I have a generl problem more than a rotor problem, because it is the end output that differ from other emulators.

Forgot to mention that I try to emulate the Enigma I and I'm using rotor I, II, III, one being the fast rotor is the I, the middle is the II and the III on the left